# Does OpenAPI support regex in path, like ExpressJS does?

Tags: swagger, openapi

For languages with diacritics it would be very useful to allow regex in paths, for example for the Portuguese word `código`, allowing both `codigo` and `código`, example:

```yaml
  /c(o|ó)digo_postal/{cp}:
    get:
      operationId: getPostalcodeInfo
      summary: Detalhes sobre Código Postal (CP4 ou CP7)
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: cp
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            pattern: /^\d{4}(\p{Dash}?\d{3})?$/u
          examples:
            cp4:
              value: '2495'
              summary: Código Postal CP4
            cp7:
              value: '2495-300'
              summary: Código Postal CP7
          description: Código Postal
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/json'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Detalhes sobre Código Postal CP4 ou CP7
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                oneOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/CP4'
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/CP7'
        '404':
          description: Código Postal não encontrado
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string
```

But it is failing on my validator. I read the [specs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/) but they don't mention anything.

Comment: Why do you think it "would be useful"? It hurts most developers every time they need to work with such kind of API.

Comment: @VasilyKolesnikov because English although practical since it hasn't diacritics, it is not the only language in the world.

Comment: UTF-8 is not the only encoding in the world. Yet it's very advisable to use UTF-8. In the same way, you should use English. What you're doing here is overcomplicating things. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenAPI does not support regex in paths.

It does support references though, so you could have both paths be a simple `$ref` entry to the same Path Item, effectively allowing what you're suggesting here.

I think the other alternative is simply to use a sanitised string (I think I'd be tempted to do that for paths anyway), but as an English-only speaker, I don't know if that makes sense in the context or not.

Comment: what is a sanitised string?

Comment: removal of unsafe characters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization